# The code mixes the rows up after use. Is there a better code

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets:

1- **ETU** (containing all the data with headers)

2- **MA** (only having headers)

I want all the rows containing the word **MSISAC** to be cut and pasted in the second worksheet (**MA**).
However my code below seems to mix up the cells in the first tab (**ETU**) after moving the requested rows to the second worksheet (**MA**).
I end up having the first tab with different values in column **AB**.

```
Sub Separate_MSISAC()
    Dim wsOne As Worksheet 'etc
    Dim lastRowOne As Long 'etc

    Set wsOne = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("ETU")
    Set wsTwo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MA")

    lastRowOne = wsOne.Cells(wsOne.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowtwo = wsTwo.Cells(wsTwo.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For i = lastRowOne To 1 Step -1
        If wsOne.Range("AB" & i).Value = "MSISAC" Then
            wsTwo.Rows(lastrowtwo).Value = wsOne.Rows(i).Value
            wsOne.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
            lastrowtwo = lastrowtwo + 1
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Would you have an alternative to solve it? This is the last part of the full code and this is where it fails. Thanks!

Comment: Code seems fine to me.

Comment: Instead of a loop, would you consider an AutoFilter, whereby you could transfer all MISISAC-containing rows in one go (i.e. no need for a loop) and then do a sort on wsOne to move the blank rows to the end?